# Ant load property file and pass value as arg when exec java file

Tags: file, ant, load, properties, arguments

How can I load a value from a property file and pass it as arg when I want to execute a java file?

The content the file of aa.properties:
home_path=C:/myhome/apps

The ant:

```
<target name="tst">
  <property file="aa.properties"/>
    <property name="homepath" value="${home_path}/"/>
      <java classpathref="clspath" classname="com.mytest.myapp" fork="true">
        <arg value="${homepath}"/>
      </java>
</target>
```

Comment: That looks like the correct steps (although you could just use `<arg value="${home_path}"/>` without the intermediate `homepath` property). Is something not working?

Answer (score 1):

you pass it like any other argument to the java task via nested arg values or arg line
Note that vmargs like f.e. -Dwhatever=foobar are passed as jvmarg to the java task

f.e. your propertyfile aa.properties looks like :

```
vmarg.foo=-Dsomevalue=whatever
arg.key=value
arg.foo=bar
...
```

ant then

```
<target name="tst">
 <property file="aa.properties"/>
 <property name="homepath" value="${home_path}/"/>
 <java classpathref="clspath" classname="com.mytest.myapp" fork="true">
  <jvmarg value="${vmarg.foo}"/>
  <arg value="${homepath}"/>
  <arg value="${arg.key}"/>
  <arg value="${arg.foo}"/>
  ...
 </java>
</target>
```

Comment: Hello

I don't know why the 2nd arg is start with "${home_path}" Doesn1t contain the value of home_path

Comment: i just used the propertyname ${homepath} from the example of your question

Comment: Try `echo`ing the properties to see if they contain what you expect. The syntax you provided should work.